# angularjs-nvd3-directives updating data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

Good afternoon

I have a angular controller which has data that i show in a chart

```
<nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart
                ng-model="Data"
                data="Data"
                id="exampleId"
                xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
                yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
                height={{height}}
                showValues="true"
                color="colorFunction()"
                showXAxis="true"
                margin="{left:100}"
                interactive="true"
                >
            <svg></svg>
</nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart>
```

EDIT:
What the app needs to do is show all the data in an array and the user can adjust 1 element of that array

i tried simulating this for now with a button on the page with ng-click which executes the following method which adjusts 1 element in the array

```
$scope.buttonClick = function(){

        $scope.Data[0].values[0][1] = 2345; //this changes the data but does not update the chart

        $scope.Data = [
            {
                key: "timeData",
                values: [
                    ["test", 1234]
                ]
            }
        ] //this completely overrides the array and replaces it (which i dont want)
    };
```

The controller updates the Data but the chart does not update

I tested this with showing the first entry from the data in a paragraph which does update correctly

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this

(link to directive used in angular [chart directive](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives))

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you update the data?   I just did it in a fiddle with no issue ... http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/A6Tk5/

Comment: thanks for the help already, with looking at the fiddle you did i atleast saw it change which is already a step forward, I editted my post a bit to show you what the code does and what i tried to do to change the data. in the buttonClick method you see 2 things i tried, once which actually updates and one that updates the data but not the chart. I don't know why it does this ... Regards

Comment: It doesn't know the data is changing... it only looks at the reference to `$scope.Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source you need to set `objectequality="false".`  It sets up a `$scope.$watch(data, objectequality).`

I am no expert on this directive but try:

```
<nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart
      ...
      objectequality="false"
      ...
>
        <svg></svg>
</nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please post your solution.

The documentation says to set `objectequality="true"`

Ref: [nvd3](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/159)

Comment: That's how it works, with objectequality="true", since I got the data from a $resource, the object is created before I fetch the data, then I push the data to an empty array of options

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this methode:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.api.refresh();
}, 1);
```